# How can I make a spinner that works on word prediction (aka auto-suggest)

Tags: android, spinner, autosuggest

I need to make a spinner or whatever it is, which will leave only the relevant options,
depending on what the user started typing:

ex:

> options are: united states, italy, russia, denmark.
>
> user types "uni"
>
> Then, "united states" is the only option left.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely the [auto complete text view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yerr looking ferr a good ol' SearchView with suggestions, mate!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchSuggestions

Takes a tick to do it, but works like a charm.